# Removing Whitespace below the content in Webpage

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I am relatively new to Web Development and am following Colt Steele's udemy course, I started doing this landing page but towards the end when I try to set the height of HTML to 100% and then there's like whitespace down. I have tried to search for a reason and I think my div container's height is causing some issues.

[image: The whitespace]

P.S: I also tried to make the HTML height auto which worked fine, but then again causes an issue in responsive mode, and even the navbar size decreases and doesn't cover to the end of the screen.

```css
  body{
        background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517331156700-3c241d2b4d83?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=748&q=80);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        color: white;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    
    html{
        height: auto;
    }
    
    
    #content{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 25%;
    }
    
    h1{
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 5em;
    }
    
    hr.new1 {
        border-top: 1px solid white;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Puurefect Match</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>              
            </li>
            
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register
                  </a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
        
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="content">
                    <h1>Puurefect Match</h1>
                    <h3>The only Human-Feline Dating app</h3>
                    <hr class="new1">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get Started</button>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @alwaysHelping I have uploaded a picture regarding the problem.

Comment: See my answer below. If i have solved your question would you mind [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and giving it an upvote. Thanks

Comment: I wonder where is your <form> starting tag? :P

Comment: @gpl there is no form utilized here.

Comment: Then what happening after       </ul>
      </form> in 2nd <ul>tag which includes Sign In and Register ? From where this closing </form> tag popped ?

Comment: @gpl Jus checked out, and In bootstrap there was a form which i removed but forgot to remove </form>

Comment: @ChrisM </form> is not the issue.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping it might be an issue later. Haven't said it is an issue in this problem but it is surely an error.

Comment: I can't see that whitespace: https://ibb.co/PjVvzhL(UC Web based on Google Chrome), https://ibb.co/CPG0Wm0 (Mozilla Firefox). Your code is fine except that </form>. It only showing if I zoomed-out in mozilla to full extent (50% I think). No problem in UC. I wonder if anybody read web page by making text that small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `height: 100%` to your `body` and `html` as well to make sure the body changes dynamically when window size changes.

[My Chrome View](https://pasteboard.co/Jlo8ISH.png)

**Live Demo:** (Run snippet below and click full screen to see the image is cover in the page and there is no white space.)

**Edit:** Bootstrap has its own `alot` of native `flex box` `classes` which you can use instead of custom CSS. We can just use `align-items-center` and `h-100` to make sure about content text stays in middle and good things it will be repsonsive as well. We do `not` need to use any Custom CSS `padding` or `margin` on content.

```css
body {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517331156700-3c241d2b4d83?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=748&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {}

#content {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 5em;
}

hr.new1 {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>PURFECT MATCH</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Puurefect Match</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register
              </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
        <div id="content">
          <h1>Puurefect Match</h1>
          <h3>The only Human-Feline Dating app</h3>
          <hr class="new1">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get Started</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: For some reason I think this issue with me is related to the browser, I have tried Chrome and Firefox in which i still see a little whitespace, but in Microsoft EDGE i Dont see any.

Comment: @ChrisM I have tested the code both `firefox` and `chrome` - its working perfectly. May be you need to update your `chrome` to the latest version that might help. I do `not` even use microsoft egde. Let me know

Comment: I updated my Chrome and yet this whitespace thingy persists :(

Comment: @ChrisM Wao. There is something going on there. I will add an image of my chrome view in my answer. Can you `Run Snippet` above and click full screen on the right and check how do you see it there ?

Comment: @ChrisM This is my chrome view : https://pasteboard.co/Jlo8ISH.png

Comment: Thats my view. ugh! @AlwaysHelping
https://pasteboard.co/JlodaXO.png

Comment: @ChrisM Wao. That totally confusing. Are you sure you are copying the exact code i have in answer ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I think it has got something to do with my div #content
Preview: https://pasteboard.co/JlofnsuQ.png

Comment: @ChrisM Can you remove `padding` from the `#content` and see it that fixes it ?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JlozqiM.png That actually fixed it!
But now I want the text in between of the page

Comment: @ChrisM Sure. Let me update my answer to achieve that as well.

Comment: I achieved that right now, Thanks a lot for the help!
https://pasteboard.co/JloCvvq.png
P.S: I would like to see your changes tho and I would mark it as the answer. Jus update me when your done

Comment: @ChrisM Please check my edited answer. I am not using any custom padding or margins to align my text in the middle of the screen. I have added some details in the answer for you as well. Do not forget to accept the answer if i have helped and solved the question. Thanks :)